# SVG gradient does not yield correct start and end colours

Tags: colors, svg, gradient

I have a linear gradient from #F1BC6D to #EA5D49. But the rendered colours are not close to these start and stop values. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="40px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 40 36" version="1.1" height="36px">
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="a" x2="50%" x1="50%" y2="100%">
   <stop stop-color="#F1BC6D" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#EA5D49" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
 </defs>
 <path d="m29.885 33.047c-4.667 2.696-11.084 2.973-17.54 0.206-5.2273-2.224-9.5646-6.117-12.345-10.565 1.3346 1.112 2.8916 2.002 4.5598 2.78 6.6672 3.125 13.333 2.911 18.024 0.008-0.003-0.003-0.005-0.005-0.007-0.008-6.673-5.116-12.345-11.789-16.571-17.238-0.8901-0.8898-1.5574-2.002-2.2247-3.0029 5.1159 4.671 13.235 10.565 16.126 12.234-6.116-6.451-11.566-14.458-11.344-14.236 9.676 9.787 18.685 15.348 18.685 15.348 0.298 0.168 0.528 0.308 0.713 0.433 0.195-0.496 0.366-1.011 0.51-1.545 1.557-5.672-0.222-12.123-4.115-17.461 9.008 5.4495 14.347 15.681 12.122 24.245-0.058 0.231-0.121 0.459-0.189 0.683 0.026 0.031 0.052 0.063 0.078 0.096 4.448 5.561 3.225 11.455 2.669 10.343-2.413-4.722-6.88-3.278-9.151-2.32z" fill="url(#a)"/>
</svg>
```

In Safari and Chrome, the colours I get from the top and bottom are: #E4B274 and #CB674E.

Comment: Your SVG works exactly as expected, which suggests a bug in whatever software you use to render the SVG. As such it is off-topic here but with some more details (screenshots, specification of software) it **may** be on-topic on [su].

Comment: Which program are you using to render the SVG?

Comment: @jpaugh Safari and Chrome